# How to pick up all numbers from string

Tags: php, regex, url, numbers

I have a string that looks like `abc,5,7` from which I want to get the numbers.

I've come up with this:

```
^(?<prefix>[a-z]+)(,(?<num1>\d+?))?(,(?<num2>\d+?))?$#i
```

but it will only work with 2 numbers, and my string has a variable number of numbers. I don't know how to change the regex to account for that. Help please

Comment: can't you try explode with `,`  and then iterate the array with `is_numeric()` condition on the value ?

Comment: If the prefix at start is mandatory, try `(?:^[a-z]+|\G(?!^)),\K\d+` [see demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yP5fT8/2). Else just use `\d+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?php
$string = "abc,5,7";
$int = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $string), 10);
echo $int;
?>
```

Also you can Use this regular expression `!\d!`

```
<?php
$string = "abc,5,7";
preg_match_all('!\d!', $string, $matches);
echo (int)implode('',$matches[0]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`explode` with comma `,` is the easiest way.

but if you insist to do it with `regexp`

here is how

```
$reg = '#,(\d+)#';

$text = 'abc,5,7,9';

preg_match_all($reg, $text, $m);

print_r($m[1]);

/* Output
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 9
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

try this . very simple use preg_replace('/[A-Za-z,]+/', '', $str);// removes alphabets from the string and comma

```
<?php
$str="bab,4,6,74,3668,343";
$number = preg_replace('/[A-Za-z,]+/', '', $str);// removes alphabets from the string and comma
echo $number;// your expected output 
?>
```

expected output

```
46743668343
```